# How was SEELE able to find the last angel (Kaworu)?

Tags: anime, evangelion

At the end of the original series, Gendo Ikari seems to be diverging from their original idea, and to prevent this SEELE (committee?) sends Kaworu to NERV directly, aiming to make contact with the angel in terminal dogma.
Ritsuko seemed to know the real identity, so why let it pass? (this is a comment not the question).

But how was SEELE able to do this (detect, find and recruit the fifth child)? It is supposed to be the case that no one knows where the angels come from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**They had him since the begginning.**

Kaworu body was created as result of the Contact Experiment with Adam, from the fusion of the DNA of an unknown donor and the flesh of the Angel. SELEE then salvaged Adam's Soul in his body. This is hinted in differents points during some dialogues.

> **Man E**: "The contact experiment with the donor is scheduled for the
> 13th of next month. There will be time for any adjustments."
>
> (*later*) **Woman B**: "The genes that dived into Adam have already undergone
> physical fusion!"
>
> <sub><sub>*Neon Genesis Evangelion. Episode 21*</sub></sub>

> **Hyuga**: "But the one thing we do know [about Kaworu Nagisa] is that his birthday coincides with the Second Impact".
>
> ---
>
> **SEELE A** (speaking to Kaworu): "[Adam's] salvaged soul exists only within you."
>
> <sub><sub>*Neon Genesis Evangelion. Episode 24 Platinum subtitles*</sub></sub>

This connection is only hinted in the original Anime, while in the Manga and in the Rebuild is stated blatantly.